# Prompt tool for Visual Studio 2010 to package xaml code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

I need a tool for rapid code generation from

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"><TextBlock Text=" " /><TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxIsReadOnly}" Text="{Binding title}" Foreground="Chocolate" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/></DockPanel>
```

in:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <TextBlock Text=": " />
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxIsReadOnly}" Text="{Binding title}" Foreground="Chocolate"   DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the text in Visual Studio XML editor and then <kbd>CTRL+K+F</kbd> to format the code.

Comment: That's fine, but where you can read about the usefulness of VS2010